# take control of pocket PC wince

Tags: windows-ce

I would like to take control of pocket PC wince from An other PC (wondows XP) through ethernet cable.
Do you know a program doing this compatible with WinCE ?

Comment: Are you targeting Wince or Windows Mobile? They are not the same. Pocket PC is an old version of Windows Mobile. Change the tagging if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you need:  (if not please clarify question)

[Logmein for Windows Mobile](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2007/06/29/logmein-remote-administration-for-windows-mobile/)

[Logmein forum](http://community.logmein.com/logmein/board/message?board.id=12&thread.id=856)

Comment: I would like to access files on the Windows CE device over the network.But File Server component is not present in the image OS.
How I can do without using internet.Baecause logmein is using internet

Comment: This is a windows CE 6.00
Marvel ARM9205